# How to add delay when submitting form using "Validate" jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I'm using [jQuery Validation Plugin](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/) to make validation for forms.

Here is a demo for the current state: https://jsfiddle.net/rrzddexr/1/

I want the validation notification appear after a time i can specify be hand (for example 3000ms), not as the provided demo where the validation messages appear immediately after i click submit

I want this purpose specially because i want to apply some js code within this delay, then the form apply its validation and show its results.

I'm something not professional at javascript. I hope i described the point clearly.

### HTML

```
<form id="contact-form" action="post">
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="cfName" id="cfName" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name">
</div><!-- .form-group end -->
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="cfEmail" id="cfEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email">
</div><!-- .form-group end -->
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea  name="cfMessage" id="cfMessage" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
</div><!-- .form-group end -->
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" class="form-control" value="Send">
</div><!-- .form-group end -->
```

### CSS

```
body {
  background: #fff;
}

/* Contact Form */
#contact-form {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 30px auto;

  input.error,
  textarea.error {
    border-color: #f33;
  }

  label.error {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
}


form {
  position: relative;
}

form .form-group {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 15px;

  &:last-child {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}

input,
input.form-control,
button,
button.form-control,
textarea,
textarea.form-control,
select,
select.form-control {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #222;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 15px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 1px solid #ebeef0;
  background: #fafbfc;
}

input:focus,
textarea:focus,
input.form-control:focus,
textarea.form-control:focus,
select:focus,
select.form-control:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: #d6d9da;
}

textarea,
textarea.form-control {
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 26px !important;
  padding-top: 11px;
  padding-bottom: 11px;
  height: 200px;
  resize: vertical;
}

form .field-icon {
  position: absolute;
  background: #eee;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #222;
  border-radius: 100%;
  font-size: 13px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

.field-icon + input[type="text"],
.field-icon + input[type="email"],
.field-icon + textarea {
  text-indent: 30px;
}

.form-inline .form-control {
  width: 100%;
}

abbr {
  cursor: help;
}

label {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  // display: inline;
  color: #222;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

label.error {
  color: #ff3333;
  display: block;
}

input[type="submit"],
input[type="submit"].form-control,
input[type="submit"],
input[type="submit"].form-control {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #ffc527;
  box-shadow: none;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  width: auto;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: none;
}

.form-inline .form-control[type="submit"] {
  width: auto;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover,
input[type="submit"]:focus,
input[type="submit"].form-control:hover,
input[type="submit"].form-control:focus {
  background: #222;
}

input[type="submit"]:focus,
input[type="submit"].form-control:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

### Javascript

```
$( "#contact-form" ).validate({
    // rules
    rules: {
        cfName: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3
        },
        cfEmail: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        cfMessage: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 8,
            maxlength: 500
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What did you mean with "... add delay on the form after making submitting..." in your second paragraph. Did you mean after click on submit button?

Comment: Yes after clicking. I want the validation notification appear after a time i can specify be hand, not as the provided demo where the validation messages appear immediately after i click submit.

Comment: What is the purpose of said weird seemingly unnecessary delay?

Comment: @Kevin .. Do you know the "Contact Form 7" plugin style where there is like a loader is appearing when clicking submit, then the validation messages is appearing? So i'm looking forward to make like this style by make this loader effect for 2 seconds, then run the validation plugin.

Comment: so... you're wanting to make the user wait 2 seconds, for no reason other than displaying a loading spinner? what a waste of the user's time.

Comment: @Kevin .. Whatever the amount of delay, in my point of view i think this could add some interactive behaviour with this loading spinner. I don't have experience to implement this idea. I hope you help me if this possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#contact-form").submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  // execute your code here
  var timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
    $( "#contact-form" ).validate({
      // rules
      rules: {
        cfName: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 3
        },
        cfEmail: {
          required: true,
          email: true
        },
        cfMessage: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 8,
          maxlength: 500
        }
      }
    });
  }, 3000)
});
```

Comment: I only had one left, so i figured i should go ahead and use it on a post i felt wasn't useful.

Comment: You're a funny guy. And you were right the post was about as useful as your  comment on why it wasn't useful. In any event, fixed. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

i'm sure there is someone out there with a nicer/neater way to do this, doing some sort of crazy recursive patterns or something..

However to accomplish what you want to do is the following (I also updated your fiddle).

Wrap your validate in a function, and bind a click handler to the submit button. Then when the user hits "submit" it fires that first, then executes your validate js.

```
$(function(){
  $( "#contact-form" ).on("click",function(){
    alert("do something");
//then run form, or call form on Callback of your other function
 checkForm();
 })
})
function checkForm(){
//your original code 
}
```

[https://jsfiddle.net/rrzddexr/4/](https://jsfiddle.net/rrzddexr/5/)

Comment: I tested your demo, but the alert is appearing when clicking on any place of the form. This is not what i'm looking for.  I want the validation notification appear after a time i can specify be hand, not as the provided demo where the validation messages appear immediately after i click submit

Comment: @MoradHamdy use the event [submit](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) instead on click and add your delay function on that place like ChrisBurns mentioned.

Comment: @StellaMaris .. The plugin is looks like making this submit event internally. Look at my demo code.